# Obtener las propiedades de una tabla HTML y guardarlas en un Json

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, mvc

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo una tabla que modifico en la pagina web mediante el mouse, puedo agrandar o achicar las columnas, quitarlas o ponerlas, etc. Lo que necesito es que una vez que mi tabla quede bien, en un archivo JSON se inserten las propiedades de esa tabla, así como los tamaños de letras, etc. La verdad soy nueva en esto y estoy atorada, cualquier ayuda sería bien recibida. Gracias.

```
nombreRealColumnaSQL{
nombreNuevoColumna: "Algun Nombre",
aliasColumna:"Algun alias",
propiedadesCelda: {
propiedades:{
estilo:{
"text-align":"left",
padding: "5px"
etc, etc
},
}
}
}
}
```